# Set the date and time from a MM/DD/YYYY h:mm formatted cell

Tags: excel, vba

By default my sheet receives a date such as 07/15/2022 20:55. I need to set the "start time" for my macro to run properly always on the day before at 23:00. Right now I subtract 1 from the original cell and get the day before, but for the hour I'm in trouble..

Comment: `dte = Int(OriginalCell) - (1/24)`

Comment: Nice, Mr Craner, thanks a lot!